# Installing R package "CATBOOST" in Win32 System

Tags: r, catboost

I have win32-system with R and Anaconda3 installed.

When I try install from R I got this error:

> [ya.bat] Error: Python not found

Then I edit "ya.bat" file by this:

> call :dbg Searching for python manually...  for %%F in ( 
>       C:\Python27\python.exe 
>       C:\Python26\python.exe 
>       **C:\Anaconda3\python.exe**  ) do ...

and start this file I got this:

> ERROR: [WinError 216] Версия "%1" не совместима с версией Windows, работающей на этом компьютере. Проверьте сведения о системе, чтобы узнать, какая версия программы x86 (32-разрядная) или x64 (64-разрядная) вам нужна, и получите ее у поставщика программного обеспечения

Can I install CATBOOST to R in Win32-system? Xgboost I can ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in [documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/r-installation-docpage/).

> Note. Installation is only supported by the 64-bit version of R